# JpaRepository - Cannot delete because exception "attempt to create delete event with null entity"

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, java-11, jparepository

I have a case related to delete an entity using java JpaRepository.

class UserLanguage:

```
@EmbeddedId
@JsonUnwrapped
private UserLanguageId userLanguageId;

private String nameEn;
private String icon;

public UserLanguage (Long userId, Long languageId) {
   this.userLanguageId = new UserLanguageId(userId, languageId);
}
```

whenever I try to delete a record using method deleteAllByUserLanguageId_UserId(userId) , it will cause

> IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event with null entity.

- userId is not null when I put log in my code.
- I have tried to debug to catch the exception, and searched many topics but still no solution.